# How to tabulate a numeric text file?

Tags: vb.net

I have a numeric text file whose data need to be tabulated. Unfortunately, depending on the input data, this text file shows numbers which are not separed, one to each other, from a fixed number of spaces and unfortunately this number of space could not be the same from a row to another.
I tried this:

```
    For Each line In RichTextBox2.Lines
        If Not line.Trim.ToString = "" Then
            Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split(" "c)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
```

and then I used to erase the blank columns. But I realised that when the number of space is different on the rows, I have data, that should fill the same column, that are on two or three different columns (with spaces). Let me provide an example:
[Here there are the numbers coming from the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwBh4.png) and [here are the tabulated  numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrOPk.png).
What I would do, is to erase all the spaces except one, in order to have these numbers equally spaced one from another. Hoping to have been clear, I thank you so much for the support

Comment: Bit hard to tell form the images, are the data fields in the file a fixed length (Including spaces and values)?  Nasty way to do it would be replace all instances of multiple spaces with a single space, then your split should work

Comment: @Hursey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately no fixed lenght for these text files. How could be possible what you're saying? I'm not an expert programmer

Comment: Probably best tactic to remove extra spaces might be using regex, which I'm not expert on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0

Comment: Use an overload of `Split` that allows you to specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. That will effectively treat multiple spaces as a single separator.

Comment: The line would look like `Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`